# Git: rebasing a branch

Tags: git, git-rebase

I'm trying to make sense of rebasing in Git and have a question whether or not it's good practice to use rebasing in this scenario:

I have a branch called 'feature' which is branched off from another branch called 'develop'. I have made several commits in 'feature' but haven't merged with 'develop' yet because the feature is still in being developed, nor have the commits in 'feature' been pushed to the remote repository.

If I now checkout 'develop' to make a few amends, is it wise to rebase it to the 'feature' branch so that 'develop' is in sync with 'feature'?

Comment: Why not to merge them then?

Comment: I haven't finished developing the feature.

Comment: Merging doesn't close branch. If you feel like changes from feature can be applied on develop then you can equally merge them. Then you continue work on feature and merge it again when it is done.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I always assumed it was best to keep any feature branch separate to develop until the feature had been fully tested and then to merge them into develop - perhaps I assumed incorrectly?

Answer (score 6):

I would rebase 'feature' on 'develop' (assuming, of course, that 'feature' is a local branch)

Merging 'develop' into 'feature' would create a redundant merge commit. But doing the rebase integrates all changes from master and lets you resolve all conflicts before 'feature' is ready to be merged with 'develop', without creating any extra commit.

There are certainly [those who disagree](http://paul.stadig.name/2010/12/thou-shalt-not-lie-git-rebase-ammend.html). But I like a clean, readable history. What I often do is that when I'm finished with the feature, I `rebase`, and then I `merge --no-ff`. That way the history still clearly shows that there has been a feature branch:

```
- * - * - - - - - - - * - * -
       \             /
        * - * - * - *
```

The thing is that I like to resolve conflicts "continuously". Whenever there is a conflict I want to know about it early so I can resolve it before it gets cumbersome to do so (analogous to the reasons for continuous integration). If I would follow that strategy that using frequent merging, I would have a *lot* of merge commits. With frequent rebases I can avoid them.

There is an alternative strategy that lets you use merging but without merge commits - you can turn on git rerere:

```
git config --global rerere.enabled true
```

[As described in this article](http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/08/rerere.html), you can then do intermediate merges, resolve conflicts, and then reset the merge commit. The rerere feature will make Git remember the conflict resolution when you do the final merge of the 'feature' branch.

Comment: @tom I interpret the OP as talking about rebasing 'feature' onto 'develop'. OP has made changes ("a few amends") in 'develop' that he would like to "sync" into 'feature'. Rebasing 'feature' onto 'develop' would make those changes available in 'feature', that is how I interpret "sync"

Comment: Thanks for all your help and advice. If I wanted to rebase 'develop' onto 'feature', would this be ok to do, or would I do what @Adrian suggests and simply merge 'feature' with 'develop' so that I'm able to see the changes when I switch back to 'develop', bearing in mind that 'feature' has not been fully tested and is still in development?

Comment: @GoonyanHarir If 'feature' was branched off 'develop' I don't quite see how you would rebase 'develop' onto 'feature. It sounds very backward to me. If you rebase 'feature' on 'develop', you will get the changes in 'develop' in 'feature'

Comment: Sorry, I should have tried to phrase my question better - How can I get the changes from 'feature' to show in 'develop' without a merge.

Comment: @GoonyanHarir ok. If that is your goal, then cherry-picking the important parts of 'feature' into 'develop' might be a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

#### Adding all the commits to *feature*

The following will result in all the commits made on the *develop* branch since the split being applied to the *feature* branch, without affecting *develop*.

Current state:

```
M1---M2---D1--D2--T1--T2  develop
      \
       F1--F2  feature
```

Option 1: merge *develop* into *feature*
`git checkout feature; git merge develop`

```
M1---M2---D1--D2--T1--T2  develop
      \                \
       F1--F2-----------F3  feature
```

Option 2 (originally suggested by Klas Mellbourn): rebase *feature* onto *develop*
`git checkout feature; git rebase develop`

```
M1---M2---D1--D2--T1--T2  develop
                       \
                        F1'--F2'  feature
```

The `rebase` creates a nicer history but it is problematic if there are other commits based on *feature*. In your case there aren't, so it is not a problem.

#### Adding some commits to *feature*

If you cannot do the above (maybe the commits `D1` and `D2` are not ready to make their way into *feature* yet) you can use `git cherry-pick` to copy the commits over to *feature*:

```
M1---M2---D1--D2--T1--T2  develop
      \
       F1--F2--T1'--T2'  feature
```

A `git rebase` would move the commits, not copy them.

#### Separate topic branch

An alternative workflow is to make the new commits in a new topic branch based on an early common ancestor:

```
       T1--T2  topic
      /
M1---M2---D1--D2  develop
      \
       F1--F2  feature
```

With such a graph *topic* could me merged into both *develop* and *feature* without introducing unwanted or duplicate commits.